# what is difference between Orderer validating and peer validation before commit block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have query, i am reading the hyperledger fabric article, In article its mention that, User *User1* sends a transaction *Tx1* to Peer *P1*, Peer *P1* endose *E1*, the transaction *Tx1*, the transaction received back to *user1* and he pass it to order *or1*, And order will validate the *Tx1* and create the block and it will commit.

My Question is :

```
  1. when order is committing the block, why it will send to peer P1 back.
  2. In article they mention Peer P1 is also validate Tx1, How Peer will 
     verify the Tx1.
  3. If Peer P1 verify the Tx1, does Peer P1 also keep the record of all the Peers and Orderer details.
  4. If Peer also can Validate the Tx1, best thing is to apply the 
    block/Batch creation mechanism to Peer directly, so no need of orderer. i have doubt please suggest me.
```

Comment: Have you seen these 2 documents in the Official Fabric Documentation?
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html
  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html#swimlane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application “broadcasts” the transaction proposal and response
>   within a “transaction message” to the ordering service. The
>   transaction will contain the read/write sets, the endorsing peers
>   signatures and the Channel ID. The ordering service does not need to
>   inspect the entire content of a transaction in order to perform its
>   operation, it simply receives transactions from all channels in the
>   network, orders them chronologically by channel, and creates blocks of
>   transactions per channel.

Read this doc: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html

However, I will answer to your questions:

1. when order is committing the block, why it will send to peer P1 back.

   A) Orderer will just receive pool of transactions and form blocks and ship to committing peers, it will not do any validation and it creates blocks so orderer also will have a copy of the ledger
2. In the article they mention Peer P1 is also validate Tx1, How Peer will 
    verify the Tx1.

   A) If Peer1 is an endorsing peer then it will **simulate** the ledger by making the transaction commit and it will record the behavior it will send back to the user.
3. If Peer P1 verify the Tx1, does Peer P1 also keep the record of all the Peers and Orderer details.

   A) By default all endorsing peers are commiting peers, so yes it will keep
4. If Peer also can Validate the Tx1, best thing is to apply the 
   block/Batch creation mechanism to Peer directly, so no need of orderer. i have doubt please suggest me.

   A) Here if you come from ethereum background orderer is like a miner, here he will not do any calculations simply form batches and ship to peers like a postman job.

Comment: does orderer create the block only if transaction exists, or it will create empty block also ?

Comment: There is a two checks you can control block limit and timeout. So based on timeout even if no transactions present at particular time a lot Orderer will creat empty blocks

Comment: @NarendranathReddy, If orderer doesn't have the transaction, It won't create an empty block after the batch timeout.
There are two condition